# Unable to SSH on my ubuntu server with a user different from root

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

When I try to ssh to my Ubuntu Server as a user different from root the connection never works and the session is never established. However connecting from other computers works perfectly, so it must be an issue of my mac. I don't know what to do. Suggestions?

```
▶ ssh thefe@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -vvv
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
```

And no more output gets printed...I'm stuck!

While from root

```
▶ ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -vvv
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:22 as 'root'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:K+u2j5erBu0FjLlnky42rz1OcWocEvKvZWTYSYAojZY
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jk0NUsRYmx1AZn7IuQLETN2emKSAkBhDao4xBvbAs3g
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jk0NUsRYmx1AZn7IuQLETN2emKSAkBhDao4xBvbAs3g
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/thefe/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:jk0NUsRYmx1AZn7IuQLETN2emKSAkBhDao4xBvbAs3g
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com with ED25519 SHA256:jk0NUsRYmx1AZn7IuQLETN2emKSAkBhDao4xBvbAs3g
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519 SHA256:jk0NUsRYmx1AZn7IuQLETN2emKSAkBhDao4xBvbAs3g
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:G/fUdfsvO8DDVKP/egzqmb0Z6FBQd/QpXB/zCLR2DDY
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:U6x4RPdmzrxXVqS7rdDZNNvtcHgMlH+MCO3xVDcLg+0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:K+u2j5erBu0FjLlnky42rz1OcWocEvKvZWTYSYAojZY
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2 for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/thefe/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.4.19"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_CELLAR
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env INFOPATH
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug3: Ignored env CLOUDSDK_PYTHON
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_SDK
debug3: Ignored env FLUTTER_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env REACT_EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env NVM_CD_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env NVM_BIN
debug3: Ignored env NVM_INC
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env GREP_COLOR
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-67-generic x86_64)

<Session is now active and working>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is a `ll` from `/root/.ssh`

```
▶ ll
total 16K
-rw------- 1 root root  112 May  9 09:55 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 root root 3.4K May  6  2020 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  741 May  6  2020 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  840 Aug 29  2022 known_hosts
```

`/home/thefe/.ssh` is a empty folder

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145893/discussion-on-question-by-ale-thefe-unable-to-ssh-on-my-ubuntu-server-with-a-use); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that it works with your custom domain `my-domain.com` because of the configuration of the Domain Name System (DNS) of your domain. Your SSH configuration on the server initially allowed direct root login, but the configuration for non-root users may be set up to require additional steps or additional authentication. This configuration is typically done for security reasons to enforce the use of domain names and prevent direct access via IP addresses.

By enforcing DNS name-based authentication, the server can ensure that users are connecting to the intended domain and not bypassing any potential security measures or access restrictions put in place for specific domain names.

Edit: The user commented that the DNS name was used instead of the IP address which worked and solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the server was assigned to my custom domain (let's call it `my-domain.com`). So instead of putting `ssh thefe@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` if I put `ssh thefe@my-domain.com` it works perfectly. root user works both with ip address or domain name. I really don't know why but now it works!

Comment: Does the domain name resolve to exactly the same IP address as before?

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: `grep -Ei 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX|my-domain.com' ~/.ssh/config /etc/ssh/ssh_config` will most likely pick out any specific custom configuration entries (for your true values of `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` and `my-domain.com`, of course). Does anything match?

Comment: should I do this from local or from remote? and if from remote which user?
Anyway I tried both and `~/.ssh/config` doesn't exist from local nor remote, while `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` works but grep finds nothing with IP nor domain